# select those event that came on same day from table which contain date column in milliseconds?

Tags: database, sqlite, date, select

i am create table which contain column of date which in in **milliseconds**.
i want to select all data of particular day from that table.

Table Event

```
event_id      event_titile     event_date_in_milli_sec

11             deo's B'day         1335901530000 
12             MJ B'day            1337805930000  
13             MR B'day            1337885130000 
14             RJ B'day            1338579930000
```

as show in above table structure of event table in that table row no 2 and 3 are both event are created in same day so i want to select those event that come on same day

please help me thanks in adv.

Comment: i'd start from figuring out what an `event_date_in_milli_sec` value of 0 means

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm 
copy the above value into millisecond converter it show the date

Comment: i just want list out all event_tittle according to date

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select event_id,
       event_title,
       datetime(event_date_in_milli_sec / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) as dt
from table_events
order by dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long[] getBoundaryDates (Date d) {
    long[] r = new long[2];
    d.setHours(0);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    r[0] = d.getTime();
    d.setHours(23);
    d.setMinutes(59);
    d.setSeconds(59);
    r[1] = d.getTime();
    return r;
}

public Void getData(Date date) {
    long[] _l = HelperFunctions.getBoundaryDates(d);
    String query = "select * from  TABLE_EVENTS WHERE "
        + KEY_EVENT_TIMESTAMP_START  + " >= " + _l[0]
        + " and " + KEY_EVENT_TIMESTAMP_START + " <= "
        +  _l[1];
}
```